# Google Sheet API issue Golang

Tags: go, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I cant figure out how to change the value of one cell. Its failing on the rb variable values. I've been reading the docs and searching the web with no luck.

```
// The ID of the spreadsheet to update.
    spreadsheetId := "XXXXX" // TODO: Update placeholder value.

    // The A1 notation of the values to update.
    range2 := "B2" // TODO: Update placeholder value.

    // How the input data should be interpreted.
    valueInputOption := "" // TODO: Update placeholder value.

    rb := &sheets.ValueRange{
        "range":          string,
        "majorDimension": enum(Dimension),
        "values":         []string{"34344",},
    }

    resp, err := sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Values.Update(spreadsheetId, range2, rb).ValueInputOption(valueInputOption).Context(ctx).Do()
```

Comment: When you in inialize the `rb` var, you use `string` as a value of `range`, but it's a type and not the name of a var.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to put the values to Google Spreadsheet using googleapis with golang.
- You have already been able to get and put values by using Sheets API.

  - In your script, although you don't show the script for authorizing, `sheetsService` can be used for putting values using Sheets API.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- I think that in your script, `valueInputOption`, `rb` and the request for putting values are required to be modified.

  - For example, please put `USER_ENTERED` to `valueInputOption`.
  - About `rb`, I think that [jmaitrehenry's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61922120/google-sheet-api-issue-golang#comment109522970_61922120) is correct. As additional modification point, `Values` is `[][]interface{}`. And in this case, `MajorDimension` uses `ROWS` as a sample.
  - About the request, I think that in this case, `Context(ctx)` is not required.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this, please set the Spreadsheet ID.

```
spreadsheetId := "###"
range2 := "b2"
values := [][]interface{}{[]interface{}{"b2", "c2", "d2"}, []interface{}{"b3", "c3", "d3"}}
valueInputOption := "USER_ENTERED"
rb := &sheets.ValueRange{
    MajorDimension: "ROWS",
    Values:         values,
}
resp, err := sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Values.Update(spreadsheetId, range2, rb).ValueInputOption(valueInputOption).Do()
```

- When `sheetsService` can be used for putting values, When you run the script, the values of `b2, c2, d2` and `b3, c3, d3` are put to the cells "B2:D3" in the 1st tab on Google Spreadsheet.

#### Note:

- In this case, `range2` is a1Notation. For example, when you want to put the values to the sheet name of `Sheet2`, please set `range2 := "Sheet2!b2"`. When `range2 := "b2"` is used, the value is put to the 1st tab on the Google Spreadsheet. Please be careful this.
- As the scope for putting values, in this case, please set `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`.

#### References:

- [googleapis for golang](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)