# Golang - Google Sheet - updating one cell

Tags: go, google-sheets

I have it reading just fine and not complaining about auth during write operations. I get no errors but its not doing anything. I am new to Go, how can I log the results of the _, err = srv.Spreadsheets.Values.Update(spreadsheetId, writeRange, &vr).ValueInputOption("RAW").Do()

Also a bonus, any idea why its not working? I just want to update one cells value.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "golang.org/x/net/context"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
    "google.golang.org/api/sheets/v4"
)

// Retrieve a token, saves the token, then returns the generated client.
func getClient(config *oauth2.Config) *http.Client {
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    tokFile := "token.json"
    tok, err := tokenFromFile(tokFile)
    if err != nil {
        tok = getTokenFromWeb(config)
        saveToken(tokFile, tok)
    }
    return config.Client(context.Background(), tok)
}

// Request a token from the web, then returns the retrieved token.
func getTokenFromWeb(config *oauth2.Config) *oauth2.Token {
    authURL := config.AuthCodeURL("state-token", oauth2.AccessTypeOffline)
    fmt.Printf("Go to the following link in your browser then type the "+
        "authorization code: \n%v\n", authURL)

    var authCode string
    if _, err := fmt.Scan(&authCode); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to read authorization code: %v", err)
    }

    tok, err := config.Exchange(context.TODO(), authCode)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve token from web: %v", err)
    }
    return tok
}

// Retrieves a token from a local file.
func tokenFromFile(file string) (*oauth2.Token, error) {
    f, err := os.Open(file)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer f.Close()
    tok := &oauth2.Token{}
    err = json.NewDecoder(f).Decode(tok)
    return tok, err
}

// Saves a token to a file path.
func saveToken(path string, token *oauth2.Token) {
    fmt.Printf("Saving credential file to: %s\n", path)
    f, err := os.OpenFile(path, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, 0600)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to cache oauth token: %v", err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    json.NewEncoder(f).Encode(token)
}

func main() {
    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("credentials.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to read client secret file: %v", err)
    }

    // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved token.json.
    config, err := google.ConfigFromJSON(b, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to parse client secret file to config: %v", err)
    }
    client := getClient(config)

    srv, err := sheets.New(client)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve Sheets client: %v", err)
    }

    // Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
    // https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
    spreadsheetId := "16eQPQuIw0JBG3lCLdsLEdEfaJO0Hll0GfahdpNGoxhw"
    readRange := "DE Stats!A1:B4"
    resp1, err := srv.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, readRange).Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve data from sheet: %v", err)
    }

    if len(resp1.Values) == 0 {
        fmt.Println("No data found.")
    } else {
        for _, row := range resp1.Values {
            // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
            fmt.Printf("%s, %s\n", row[0], row[1])
        }
    }

    // The ID of the spreadsheet to update.
    //spreadsheetId := "16eQPQuIw0JBG3lCLdsLEdEfaJO0Hll0GfahdpNGoxhw" // TODO: Update placeholder value.
    //range2 := "DE Stats!B1"
    //values := []interface{{}}{"121212"}}
    //valueInputOption := "USER_ENTERED"
    //rb := &sheets.ValueRange{
    //  MajorDimension: "ROWS",
    //  Values:         values,
    //}
    //resp2, err := srv.Spreadsheets.Values.Update(spreadsheetId, range2, rb).ValueInputOption(valueInputOption).Do()

    // TODO: Change code below to process the `resp` object:
    //fmt.Printf("%#v\n", resp2)

    // Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
    // https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
    //spreadsheetId := "16eQPQuIw0JBG3lCLdsLEdEfaJO0Hll0GfahdpNGoxhw"
    //readRange := "DE Stats!A1:B4"
    resp3, err := srv.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, readRange).Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve data from sheet: %v", err)
    }

    if len(resp3.Values) == 0 {
        fmt.Println("No data found.")
    } else {
        for _, row := range resp3.Values {
            // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
            fmt.Printf("%s, %s\n", row[0], row[1])
        }
    }
}
func write() {
    //ctx := context.Background()
    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./credentials.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to read client secret file: %v", err)
    }

    // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
    // at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-go-quickstart.json
    config, err := google.ConfigFromJSON(b, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to parse client secret file to config: %v", err)
    }
    client := getClient(config)

    srv, err := sheets.New(client)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve Sheets Client %v", err)
    }

    spreadsheetId := "16eQPQuIw0JBG3lCLdsLEdEfaJO0Hll0GfahdpNGoxhw"

    writeRange := "DE Stats!A1:A2"

    var vr sheets.ValueRange

    myval := []interface{}{"One", "blah"}
    vr.Values = append(vr.Values, myval)

    _, err = srv.Spreadsheets.Values.Update(spreadsheetId, writeRange, &vr).ValueInputOption("RAW").Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve data from sheet. %v", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: did you check the response returned by that function call?

Comment: @Adam Stogner Can I ask you about how do you want to do your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/61922120

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to put the value to the cells "A1:A2" on the sheet `DE Stats`.

How about this answer?

#### Modification points:

I think that the scripts of `main()` and `write()` for getting and putting values are correct. But it is required to modify a little.

- In your script, the function of `write()` is not used. `srv.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, readRange).Do()` is run. But if the cells `DE Stats!A1:B4` have not no values, `No data found.` is shown.
- In your script, you are trying to use 2 independent scopes as one `credentials.json`. In your case, in order to use `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets` for getting and putting values as the scope.
- In your script, from `writeRange := "DE Stats!A1:A2"`, it is try to put to the values to the cells "A1:A2". But you use `myval := []interface{}{"One", "blah"}`. In this case, an error occurs. So please modify the range or value. In this answer, the range is modified.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please modify `main()` as follows. And then, **please delete the file of `token.json` of `tokFile := "token.json"` and reauthorize the scope. By this, new scope is reflected to the access token and refresh token. Please be careful this.**

```
func main() {
    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./credentials.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to read client secret file: %v", err)
    }
    config, err := google.ConfigFromJSON(b, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to parse client secret file to config: %v", err)
    }
    client := getClient(config)
    srv, err := sheets.New(client)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve Sheets Client %v", err)
    }

    spreadsheetId := "16eQPQuIw0JBG3lCLdsLEdEfaJO0Hll0GfahdpNGoxhw"

    // Put values to "DE Stats!A1:B1".
    writeRange := "DE Stats!A1"
    var vr sheets.ValueRange
    myval := []interface{}{"One", "blah"}
    vr.Values = append(vr.Values, myval)
    _, err = srv.Spreadsheets.Values.Update(spreadsheetId, writeRange, &vr).ValueInputOption("RAW").Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve data from sheet. %v", err)
    }

    // Get values from "DE Stats!A1:B4".
    readRange := "DE Stats!A1:B4"
    resp1, err := srv.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, readRange).Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve data from sheet: %v", err)
    }
    if len(resp1.Values) == 0 {
        fmt.Println("No data found.")
    } else {
        for _, row := range resp1.Values {
            fmt.Printf("%s, %s\n", row[0], row[1])
        }
    }
}
```

- In this modified script, at first, the values of `"One", "blah"` are put to the cells "A1:B1" on the sheet `DE Stats`, and the values of cells "A1:B4" on the sheet `DE Stats` are retrieved.

#### Note:

- In your script of `write()`, the values of `"One", "blah"` are put to the cells "A1:B1".

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)